# 食べる物 and 食べ物 differ

Tags: word-choice

Is there anything diference between them?

Comment: You're aware of the grammatical difference, right? You're asking about  the difference between "thing that you eat" and "food". Perhaps you could clarify your question. For example, Is there a specific context where you think they might be interchangeable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Native Japanese speaker here.
"食べる物" is a phrase and is totally different from "食べ物". "食べる物" means "something to eat"; there is a noun and a verb in that phrase. On the other hand "食べ物" generally means "food", and it's considered one word.

Same with "飲み物" and "飲む物"; "飲み物" is one word meaning "drink", and "飲む物" is a phrase, meaning "something to drink".

If you're ever stuck on whether you should use 食べ物 or 食べる物, I think it would be safest to go with 食べ物, or search it up on the spot because different situations require different types of phrases.

Comment: 「話し言葉」「話す言葉」「書き言葉」「書く言葉」は大体同じだと思います。他にもいっぱいあるでしょうか。